# Nginx location random string

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

So i have this folder structure,

```
index.html
assets/
    asset.jpg
```

i want to serve files inside the assets folder using the location directive with a special twist, i want to pass a random string to the url and still serve the same file, that is handy if i want to seamlessly track the users who downloaded the image

Example:

```
http://127.0.0.1/assets/$randomstring$/asset.jpg
```

i've tried with

```
location ~ ^/(assets/.*/)$ {
        autoindex off;
        alias /var/www/assets/;
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to serve the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rewrite ^/assets/(.+)/(.+)$ /assets/$2;

location /assets {
    autoindex off;
    alias /var/www/assets/;
}
```

This should serve requests like `http://127.0.0.1/assets/$randomstring$/asset.jpg` right. You can see those random strings in your access log.